# DropBox Folder Sharing

Tags: ios, hyperlink, directory, share, dropbox

I wanted to share a folder using DropBox Sync Api.

So I called this function to get the link of the file/folder.

```
- (NSString *)fetchShareLinkForPath:(DBPath *)path shorten:(BOOL)shorten error:(DBError **)error
```

Getting the link of the **file** is not a problem.

But whenever I want to get the folder's link I get this.

> [WARNING] ERR: DROPBOX_DISALLOWED: sync.hpp:300: app is not allowed to share folder p(/e9/p8)

Does anyone have an idea why this happens? Or is there a permission type that I am missing?
Here's my setup

- Files and datastores
- No - My app needs access to files already on DropBox
- Specific file types My app only needs access to certain file types, like text or photos.
- Images `JPEG`, `GIF`, `SVG`, `RAW`, etc.
- 'Name'

I tried searching for possible answers and I think I need stackoverflow pip's help on this one 'cause I can't find the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app only has access to certain file types, but you're trying to share an entire folder. What if that folder contains files that your app can't access? I believe that apps with File type permissions currently cannot share folders at all for this reason. (They also can't move or delete folders.)

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way yet to share folders... But just that the function,fetchShareLinkForPath's description, was for files and folders that's why I wanted to confirm this one.
I've read also the same answer on other sites but those were not updated.

But if I change the permission to all files and folders then I can't use the Sync API but Core Api instead which is a bit of a different story.

Comment: No way for apps that have File type permissions, correct. If you have full Dropbox access, you can't use the Sync API (but you can create a share link for a folder with the Core API). If you have App folder permission, then you should be able to create a share link for a folder via the Sync API.